# PC not showing up in home network

Tags: windows, networking, home-networking

My XP PC isn't showing up in my home network anymore but I can still connect to it from a folder I mapped earlier (using "map a network drive"). I can also ping it.  I have the same workgroup name so that's not the problem. (other PCs on the network are Vista and Windows 7)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=4F01A31D-EE46-481E-BA11-37F485FA34EA&displaylang=en) Microsoft update to XP fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Folders control panel and toggle Simple File Sharing.

Share a folder or two.

You can map a drive other ways, like from the Tools menu in Explorer, or the NET USE command.

Comment: i have already file sharing. Folder and printer sharing worked fine for ages but now I just cant 'see' the XP computer from any of the other network PCs...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has made it almost impossible for XP to coexist with Vista/Win7 on the same network.

See this thread : [Vista pc hidden from XP?](https://superuser.com/questions/53676/vista-pc-hidden-from-xp).
We have worked very hard here to integrate XP into the network, but have not succeeded.
You might try all the advice given in this thread. It might work for you (at least for some time).

The last-ditch solution is to refer to the XP machine by its IP address. You might make its address fixed (not DHCP) and add it to the hosts files on the other machine.