# Can't share files or printers with XP and Vista

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, networking, permissions

I have two computers on a network, one running Vista Home Premium and the other running XP Home Edition SP3.  Both computers are in the same workgroup and I have set up duplicate users on the computers.  The Vista computer can access printers and files from the XP computer, but when I go to the workgroup from the XP computer and try to access files from the Vista computer a message appears that says:

\\PC is not accessible.  You might not have permission to use this network resource.  Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.  Access is denied.

What are possible causes/solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

See this thread : [Vista pc hidden from XP?](https://superuser.com/questions/53676/vista-pc-hidden-from-xp)

You might try to re-do on your network all that we tried in order to network Vista with XP.
Although we haven't been successful, it might work for you (one never knows in advance).

If everything fails, read the paragraph in my answer about "the last resort".

**EDIT**

Set Vista to a fixed IP (say 192.168.0.10).
The XP's hosts file is found in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.
Go to its end and add the line:

> 192.168.0.10    name-of-vista-machine

(the number of spaces between the address and the name isn't important).

Comment: What exactly do I have to enter in the hosts file?

Comment: That didn't work.  I guess my best option now is just to switch the printer cable and use flash drives to transfer files.

Comment: Can you see Vista from XP in Windows Explorer when you enter the address like `"\\192.168.0.10"` ? And if yes, can you see its shared printer and try to double-click on it?

Comment: It still says "access denied".

Comment: Could you describe exactly what you're doing and what's happening?

Comment: I go to "My Network Places" and then type in the Vista computer's IP address.  Then the same message described in the original post pops up.

Comment: (1) Have you done EVERYTHING that's described in the thread I cited above? (2) Do you have a Linksys router in your network ?

Comment: (1)Yes, (2)No (15 chars.)

Comment: Too many possibilities for the cause of your problems. Many report that this tool has fixed their network problems (7 days trial) : http://www.purenetworks.com/product/pro.php

Answer (score 0):

i have the same combination as u do vista/xp/linux. i have no trouble sharing files, printer or even desktops with teamviewer.
i found if in vista u set permissions to everyone u will have no problem if on the same network

Answer (score 0):

If you have a firewall enabled in both computers,
be sure the profile is set the same.
Example: Don't have one PC set as a small home or office network
and the other set to standalone computer.