# LAN Home Network with router + Wifi internet

Tags: internet, wireless-networking, home-networking, file-sharing, lan

I have Windows 7 64bit, a Belkin router, and a Wifi usb card.

I have a Windows XP computer networked and shared on the router.

I get my internet from a USB Wifi card.

I would like to use the internet off the wifi card, but also still connect to my network and get files from the XP computer.

I have the two connections working just fine. and i can get internet...
But...

The LAN is a "public network" and I can't change it to a home network.
and i cant see the XP computer or its files.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Just to be totally clear - is the "wifi usb card" a short range 802.11 wireless card or a 3G wireless modem?

Comment: 802.11 wireless card, separate network from the LAN.

Comment: So what happens when on the win7 machine, you go to start> run and enter in the UNC path for the winXP machine? The UNC name is two back slashes followed by the computer name. Example: \\winxpcomp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have Win7 Home and cannot apply the simple solution of :
Administrative Tools / Local Security Policy / Network List Manager Policies, double-click your network, tab Network location, and set its type to Private.

For Home, use this thread which is for Vista but will probably work for Win7:
[Vista Network Identification for Loopback Adpater](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistanetworking/thread/66b42761-1b8e-4302-9134-0bb685139f4e).
As registry changes are required, I advice to create first a system restore point.

> If you make the following modification
>   to the registry, Vista will ignore
>   your adapter in the Network and
>   Sharing Center and always consider
>   that adapter on a private network.
>
> Open regedit and navigate to the
>   key
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
>
> There will be multiple keys with
>   similar names, the key is that the
>   default value on this one should read
>   'Network Adapters'.
>
> Under that key there will be a bunch
>   of subkeys (depending on how many
>   network adapters you have installed)
>   and they will be four digit numbers,
>   such as 0008.  So you have to find the
>   key that corresponds to the network
>   adapter you want to modify; use the
>   DriverDesc value to help you identify
>   it.
>
> Once you have found the key, add a
>   DWORD value to the key called
>   "*NdisDeviceType" with a DWORD value
>   of 1.  Note: common mistake is to
>   leave off the asterisk, which should
>   be included as part of the value name.
>
> For more information on the values for
>   this setting, check [here](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb201634.aspx).
>
> Essentially you are setting the device
>   to be an endpoint mapper which causes
>   Vista to ignore it but still leaves it
>   functional as a network device.
>
> Usually you have to disable and then
>   enable the network adapter in the
>   Network Connections control panel in
>   order for this to take effect.  In
>   some cases you may also need to
>   reboot.

Comment: very close to what I need, but still not close enough. I want to use Wifi internet, and Network storage.

Comment: The wifi adapter can be treated as any other adapter.

Comment: This does work. But I cannot see the network shared folders in the "network" area. I am wondering if there is a less crude (registry editing) way of doing this.

Comment: Your problem is XP : Microsoft has worked very hard to motivate you to abandon it. See my answer here : http://superuser.com/questions/53676/vista-pc-hidden-from-xp/53689#53689. Even after trying there everything imaginable, we failed to connect Vista with XP. You might try giving the machines fixed IP addresses and adding them to the hosts file, then referring to the shares by their name, because connecting XP/Win7 automatically is usually a lost cause.

Comment: It may be a semi-XP network but its going through a router first. That registry hack works... for now. very dirty though. I just mapped the folders as drives.. for now.. thanks.

Comment: Will the LAN (with the XP and vista comp) Be visible to people using the Wifi?

Comment: @Tom: For the difference between Home and Public see http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Choosing-a-network-location

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Networking-home-computers-running-different-versions-of-Windows#section_3) explains how to change a public network into a private one.

Comment: That tutorial is for Vista. I am currently using Windows 7. and it will not let me do that.

Comment: I have googled around and can't find anything - as I'm sure you did too. Can you delete the network and start again in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

I looked around and found this windows 7 tutorial.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Choosing-a-network-location

It even has a video of how to do it. What you need to realize is that these default network types are configurable. You may need to do some additional tinkering to relax the security to make life easier. There are some extra features in windows that is supposed to make it easier to have a protected share. Here's another tutorial that talks about setting up a Win 7 box to allow people to connect to it. It mainly has some screens on how to get to the network type configurations. You will need admin privileges to move from public to home or work.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/share-files-and-printers-between-windows-7-and-xp/

I have a feeling though that even if you go through the process of getting windows 7 to recognize the network correctly it may still not work. Unless you have setup the windows XP system to chare files, you may still have problems. XP is a lot more annoying to get setup especially since home and pro require different procedures to get working. I've seen a number of questions on the topic of "Setting up windows XP to share files" here on superuser. I do have yet another tutorial on how Microsoft says you should do this.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304040

It's not perfect, but should get you going in the right direction.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but not close to what I need.

Answer (score -1):

Normally when using a router the wired lan and the wireless lan are two different networks and are unable to see each other; i.e unable to share files. One way of allowing this is to create a virtual wireless network and bridge it with your wired network. You may or may not be able to do this depending on your router.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I believe you may have misunderstood me. I would like to have the connections separate. One for Internet over Wifi. Lan for sharing files over home network.

Comment: On all the home routers I have used, wireless and wired clients are on the same network, get IP addresses in the same same range and can share files.