# Can't see a Windows XP computer on the network

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, networking

I have two PC's connected to the same router. One is running Vista Home Premium and the other is running XP Pro. I'm trying to reach the shares of second PC from the first PC.

I've enabled file sharing on the XP PC, I've disabled firewall and defender, and I can successfully ping it from the Vista PC. Both computers are set to the same workgroup "WORKGROUP".

However, if I try to type "\\192.168.1.2" in Windows Explorer (192.168.1.2 being the IP address of the XP PC), I get a message: "Windows can't access \\192.168.1.2... Error code: 0x80004005 Unspecified error". And If I type "net view \\192.168.1.2" in command prompt, I get "System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found."

Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: Have you tried \\MACHINENAME where MACHINENAME is the name of the XP machine?

Comment: Yes, same outcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vista pc hidden from XP?](http://superuser.com/questions/53676/vista-pc-hidden-from-xp)

Comment: Could be related, but I see the opposite of what's described there. Let me see if I can adapt that solution ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are having an authentication issue between the machines.
Attempt to access one of your shared folders by going to My Computer and clicking on Map Network Drive.

There, type in \192.168.1.2\NAMEOFSHARE, and the click on "Connect using different credentials". There, for username type in: \192.168.1.2\USERNAME where USERNAME is the name of a user on the machine you are trying to access.

Good luck!

Comment: Does not work. I'm getting errors "A device attached to the system is not functioning" and "the specified server cannot perform the requested operation" (either one or the other, apparently at random).